# .htaccess redirect with http and https

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

I need in redirect from http/site.ru to http/www.site/com and 
from https/site.ru to https/www.site.com in one htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.ru$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site\.ru$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.ru$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site\.ru$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Problem is what that conditions redirect me from https to http always. I need to save http if that was http and https, if that was https.

Comment: Use server variable `SERVER_PROTOCOL` for the protocol.

Comment: can you write more about it?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: Thanks, but i read and read that document and don't understand what going on.